# Multiple Music Libraries?

Tags: music, music-player

I keep a large number of spoken word lectures on my device, as well as my music. This makes it difficult to select ONLY one or the other. Are there any players that will allow me to easily switch back and forth between a "music" library and a "Lectures" library?

LG P500 (Optimus One)
CM7.1.0
Winamp or PlayerPro or Music (or whatever else will work)

Answer (score 1):

[DeaDBeef](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.deadbeef.android) allows you to manage multiple playlists.  The playlists are not those in a traditional sense (where you load pls, cue, etc) in that you *select directories* to populate the playlists.

If you were to store you files on your phone in such a manner:

- /sdcard/music/Lectures/..
- /sdcard/music/Music/..

You could then create two playlists, loading the respective directories.  DeaDBeeF will ask you to install a plugins pack on first launch.  [These plugins](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.deadbeef.android.freeplugins)  allows you to play mp3s, as well as FLACs and cues.

**Android Market QR**

[image: Android Market QR]

Answer (score 1):

You could separate your lecture audio from music using playlists from the native Android music player or with [DoubleTwist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer).

Another option might be [CloudAround](http://www.cloudaround.com/)( on [Google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudaround_premium)).  You can use the player to sync music from various cloud storage providers but it also allows you to hide what you don't want to see or play from your app settings.  You could hide all music files and use the player for dedicated lecture-listening.